# Teamcity - custom email notification - variable

Tags: teamcity

According to https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Customizing+Notifications

I could list all build parameters as following:

```
<#list build.parametersProvider.all?keys as param>
  ${param} - ${build.parametersProvider.all[param]}
  <br>
</#list>
```

However, this will dump hundreds of variables.

Here is some of it

dep.TS1_Testcase_Integration.system.build.number - 354

build.number - 1205

There are few parameters that I am particular interested in.

Could you please let me know how to just display those two in the email notification?

I tried to use ${build.buildNumber} and it worked.
but, ${dep.TS1_Testcase_Integration.system.build.number} shows [TEAMCITY TEMPLATE ERROR]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to build parameters is quite straight forward:

```
${build.parametersProvider.all["dep.TS1_Testcase_Integration.system.build.number"]}
${build.parametersProvider.all["build.number"]}
```

Comment: @void if it worked, would you mind accepting the answer?